# How to add html signature to node(article)?

Tags: 8, nodes

I want to add a specific html signature in the body of article if a condition is met otherwise it should not be displayed. the specific html is:

```
<div style="width: 165px; height: 50px; background-color: white; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 12px; border: 1px solid #CDCDCD; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #F0F0F0;">
    <div style="color: #35393E; text-decoration: none; display: flex; flex-direction: row;  height: 50px">
        <img src="/media/plg_content_poet/quill.svg"
             style=" width: 31px; height: 31px; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px; color: #35393E; font-family: Roboto;">
        <div>
            <p title="<?php echo $workId; ?>" style="padding-top: 10px; line-height: 15px; margin: 0; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it part of the node body. I am new to drupal and I want to know how to achieve this. I have read about twig templates and views but I can't find any example of this kind of work.

The specific action should take place when a node is published that is why  I am using `hook_node_insert()`

```
function poet_plugin_node_insert(Node $node){
    if($node->field_workid !=''){
        //adding html to node goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just render it _after_ the node body field in the template? The problem you will run into is any edit to that body field later on will likely obliterate your markup.

Comment: How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't override the node template in the theme for whatever reason, you can just append another item to the content array and change the weight of elements until everything flows as you need.

[`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.4.x) is as reasonable a place as any to make the change, something like this:

```
function MODULE_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($node->field_workid->value != '') {
    $build['signature'] = [
      '#theme' => 'MODULE_signature',
      '#work_id' => $node->field_workid->value,
      '#weight' => 10,
    ];

    $build['body']['#weight'] = 9;
  }
}

function MODULE_theme() {
  return [
    'MODULE_signature' => [
      'variables' => ['work_id' => NULL],
    ],
  ];
}
```

And the template file at MODULE/templates/MODULE-signature.html.twig:

```
<div style="width: 165px; height: 50px; background-color: white; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 12px; border: 1px solid #CDCDCD; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #F0F0F0;">
    <div style="color: #35393E; text-decoration: none; display: flex; flex-direction: row;  height: 50px">
        <img src="/media/plg_content_poet/quill.svg"
             style=" width: 31px; height: 31px; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px; color: #35393E; font-family: Roboto;">
        <div>
            <p title="{{ work_id }}" style="padding-top: 10px; line-height: 15px; margin: 0; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Unable to find template modules/poet_plugin/templates/poet-plugin-signature.html.twig in the Drupal theme registry.`  I am getting this error

Comment: Just rename the template file to poet-plugin-signature.html.twig (sorry I missed that bit out originally)

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8, you can just add it to the twig template for that content type.

Copy `node.html.twig` in your active theme to `node--(node-type)--full.html.twig` and add something like this:

```
// code...
<div class="node-body">
  {{ content|without('field_workid') }}
  {% if node.field_workid.value %}
<div style="width: 165px; height: 50px; background-color: white; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 12px; border: 1px solid #CDCDCD; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #F0F0F0;">
    <div style="color: #35393E; text-decoration: none; display: flex; flex-direction: row;  height: 50px">
        <img src="/media/plg_content_poet/quill.svg"
             style=" width: 31px; height: 31px; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px; color: #35393E; font-family: Roboto;">
        <div>
            <p title="{{ content.field_workid }}" style="padding-top: 10px; line-height: 15px; margin: 0; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
// code...
```

I would also create a `field--field-workid.html.twig` template too and nullify any field markup so its just the field value:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

The line in the template, `{{ content|without('field_workid') }}` renders all of the fields on that content type except for work id. You can also break it out and print each field individually in your template for more control:

```
{{ content.body }}
{% if node.field_workid.value %}
  // signature markup
{% endif %}

{{ content.field_some_other_fieldname }}
```

Comment: Actually I am doing this for a separate module. Where shall I add `node--article--full.html.twig` in this case?

Comment: Into the sites active theme directory, under `/templates`. Another way to do it would be implementing your own field formatter for this field type (which I assume is text), and the formatter would have a method and template that renders this information. That could be encapsulated in a module, without relying on a theme.

Comment: This page talks about it but does not show how to add a theme hook... which is what you would need in your .module file to make it all come together. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-field-formatter . The point is, then all you would need to do is set the formatter for that field to your custom one in the Manage Display tab on that node type, and order the field after the Body field. Which would be the same exact thing, sort of, I am doing in my original answer via templates.

Comment: You are saying that I should add it to to `modules/mymodule/templates/` directory?

Comment: That won't work because it has to go into the theme templates directory, not the module - which is why I then suggested a custom field formatter.

Comment: Sir I am still not able to understand it. Can you edit the answer for my case?

Comment: Linking to articles is a faux paux here, but I cannot find the right docs page on d.o. You would want something like this: https://www.tim-diels.be/blog/how-write-custom-field-formatter-drupal-8

Comment: I'm not sure a field formatter is the best solution for this one, you'd only have the workid field to tie it to, which for the sake of sanity should probably render as an integer (if it's to be rendered at all). If you can't take the template route in this answer, you can add a new render array to the content array in either `hook_preprocess_node` or `hook_node_view` which contains the HTML (preferably itself via a template/hook_theme implementation), then play with the `#weight` of the various fields in the content array until the HTML you've injected sits under the body